# |Ultra noob| possible to send keys to background window?

Tags: java, background, key

I think this is the wrong forum for these kind of question but here goes anyway.

I have basic java knowledge, and I have managed to write a very simple mmo bot for wildstar. All it does is use the `Robot class` to move the mouse around the screen to open the ingame interface and queue for battleground, then enter and just afk there until it ends and repeats the process. All this is done by checking for colors.

Now there are a core feature I would like to add, and Ive been searching for a few days but it seems like you cant do what I want in java.

**I want to send keys to the game while its in the background so i can use computer for other stuff in the meanwhile**

(why is java so bad!? ), I dont know c# or c++. Is there a way for me to do this with java or am i stuck with a useless language.

Comment: So you want us to help you write a bot that probably breaks your TOS with WildStar? Also, java isn't useless, the problem here is with the end user, not the language itself.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible, not unless you have access to the actual Game's code and can implement some kind of listener or something.

For an application to receive key events it requires to be in focus, which it is simply not like you say (running in the background while you're doing other things). Besides that, you should probably not even try doing something like that, since building a bot for a game is usually not appreciated.